# Problems after wp_set_password() containing an apostrophe

Tags: plugin-development, login, password

So we are using a couple of custom things in our WP and one of them is a PW-Recovery form. Using this internally we're setting the password with

```
wp_set_password($password, $userId)
```

Lately we realised a problem with passwords containing the apostrophe character `"`

Setting a password with this will leave the user unable to log in using the same password that was just set. We have applied nothing to the login process and I can verify that the correct password is entered into the `wp_set_password()` function as well as the login form.

Any pointers as to where I can look for potential errors would be great. Thank you for your time.

**Update 1**

Using `wp_signon()` the user is able to login using the password `Test"123`

Using `wp-login.php?page=login` and entering the password `Test"123` will not work

currently looking for all the filters that could potentionally interfere with this...

**Update 2**

Looks to me like an undocumented wordpress feature / bug?

All plugins have been deactivated. The unmodified theme `twentefifteen` has been used. Changing the password using `wp_set_password()` changes the PW in the database. However using a password with `"` or `'` will result you being *unable* to login using `wp-login.php`. It will give you invalid credentials error.

However using the same login data and `wp_signon()` it works. I'm just clueless, probably forwarding to wp bug forums.

**Update 3**

I am using this plugin snipped to reset and test the login.

```
function resetLogin() {
//    wp_set_password('Test"123', 1);
    wp_update_user([
        'ID' => 1,
        'user_pass' => 'Test"123'
    ]);
}
//add_action('after_setup_theme', 'resetLogin');

function testLogin() {
    var_dump(wp_signon([
        'user_login' => 'admin',
        'user_password' => 'Test"123',
        'remember' => true
    ], false));
}
//add_action('after_setup_theme', 'testLogin');
```

To test I am commenting in the add_action - resetLogin once, and deactivate it immediately again before doing anything on the page. This then immediately breaks the login on wp-login.php

Comment: You are getting incorrect password message or what happens when a user can't log in?

Comment: @ThemesCreator correct, sorry for not being explicit enough. Please see the second update. I can only imagine this being a bug.

Comment: I've been trying with default WordPress form to generate new password and it works perfectly with `"` and `'` characters. It must be something you are doing wrong. Can you show the full code you are using?

Comment: @cybmeta the problem clearly lies within the usage of wp_set_password() and/or wp_update_user() - I just ran my test snipped on a naked wordpress installation. (snipped see update 3)

Comment: @cybmeta Just to ping you again - the issue was that those functions require `wp_slash()` to be used. This however isn't documented, but will surely be added as now there is an open ticket for it :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The resolution is pretty simply. Those functions require the passwords to be properly escaped. So

**Instead of this:**

```
wp_set_password('Test"123', $userId);
```

**You have to do this:**

```
wp_set_password(wp_slash('Test"123'), $userId);
```

The same goes for `wp_update_user()` and `wp_signon()`. Further information and updates on the docs may be visible from this bug report:

- https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/34297#ticket

Comment: Upvote for answering your own question

Comment: WTF wordpress. That makes no sense what-so-ever. It's the wrong abstraction level to handle sql escaping and passwords aren't even stored in the database directly.

Comment: @CodesInChaos I think this goes way back to the time of magic quotes. Wordpress still does "addslashes" to every single $_POST and get variable there is. Knowing a little bit of Wordpress's internals doing this is pretty obvious - though getting to the point of realization cost me 6 hours of work Xx for a freaking addslashes.... Xx

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if this exactly what is happening to you, but this is what the codex says about wp_set_password():

> Please note: This function should be used sparingly and is really only
>   meant for single-time application. Leveraging this improperly in a
>   plugin or theme could result in an endless loop of password resets if
>   precautions are not taken to ensure it does not execute on every page
>   load.

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_set_password/

I think you should only use it to reset the password and then delete it.

Comment: I am aware of this, thank you. I am using it the way it is meant to be. As far as I can tell there is two ways to update a users password. `wp_set_password()` and `wp_update_user()` - both ultimately result in the same outcome :(

Comment: Just to ping you again - the issue was that those functions require `wp_slash()` to be used. This however isn't documented, but will surely be added as now there is an open ticket for it :)